# Pandas - Drop rows where *not* totally duplicated

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains the following columns (along with others).  I am trying to figure out how to remove **all** rows where:  For each group number in ID_Dets if there exists more than 1 unique number in ID_Dets_2 then drop all rows.

I have bolded the rows that I would want removed.  Thx!

| Index | Other Columns | ID_Dets | ID_Dets_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | aga | 4 | 5 |
| 13 | af | 2 | 3 |
| 14 | da | 3 | 4 |
| 15 | aga | 3 | 4 |
| **16** | **as** | **0** | **0** |
| **17** | **ga** | **0** | **0** |
| **18** | **asg** | **0** | **1** |
| **19** | **asa** | **0** | **1** |
| 4 | ga | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | aah | 1 | 2 |

Comment: you want to drop all non-duplicates is that the question?

Comment: your question is unclear. it seems like you ended mid-sentence and then have the dataframe.

Comment: weird, I think I had an internet issue.  fixing...    Edit: fixed

Comment: should `index=11` be removed since 4 appears twice in the last column? should `index=4` and `index=5` be removed since 2 appears twice in the last column?

Comment: Nope - there is no relationship between the values in ID_Dets and ID_Dets_2 in terms of determining uniqueness.  They're simply autoincrementing GroupBy counters.

Comment: I made a small edit to the question, maybe that makes more sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count the number of unique values per group and set a threshold to have 1 unique value:

```
df[df.groupby('ID_Dets')['ID_Dets_2'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
```

or:

```
df.groupby('ID_Dets').filter(lambda g: len(g['ID_Dets_2'].unique())<=1)
```

output:

```
   Index Other Columns  ID_Dets  ID_Dets_2
0     11           aga        4          5
1     13            af        2          3
2     14            da        3          4
3     15           aga        3          4
8      4            ga        1          2
9      5           aah        1          2
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was the end of our other question!

Comment: I see, funny ;)

Comment: In the first case, did you use the groupby action as a sort of filter? Well i be dammed didnt know i could do that

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 yes converting the output to boolean series for indexing

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by mozway is way slicker than mine, but I was working on it so might as well post it...

You can generate a list of ids to remove and then filter on that list.

```py
ids_to_remove = []
for v in df['ID_Dets'].unique():
    if df[df['ID_Dets'] == v]["ID_Dets_2"].nunique() > 1: ids_to_remove.append(a)
df = df[~df['ID_Dets'].isin(ids_to_remove)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.assign(col1=dd.ID_Dets_2.nunique()<=1)

df1.groupby('ID_Dets').apply(function1).loc[lambda dd:dd.col1]

   Index Other Columns  ID_Dets  ID_Dets_2  col1
0     11           aga        4          5  True
1     13            af        2          3  True
2     14            da        3          4  True
3     15           aga        3          4  True
8      4            ga        1          2  True
9      5           aah        1          2  True
```